# loading data from the database continuously in a jsp page

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, chat

I am making a simple chat application using jsp and servlets.
My problem is that the jsp page only shows the messages( which are stored in the database) on click of the submit button.
As a result till the type user1 doesn't click submit, he can't see what user2 has typed.
Can anyone suggest me a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this in terms of Client/Server.  If your client is not "connected" to the server, which is the case of a browser, you need to "connect" it to the server to get updated messages or text.  You can accomplish this a few ways with a client, either events or pooling a timer, even Push technology but that may be a little complex for a beginner to do.  HTML5 has a way for registering for events, javascript could pool for new messages....

Comment: well that is what I also thought. I am new to servlets and java. can u suggest how i keep sending requests to the server from my jsp page? please!

Comment: Use Ajax & Javascript.  Send the request from the browser so you hve more control of how/when ithe client is asking.  Use a timestamp each time you get a success back from the server.  Then when you send each new request, you send that date with it and ask for only new messages from that date forward.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax: http://w3schools.com/ajax/

using javascript, you control the moment when the browser connects to the server to ask for data. It still is limited - you will update the chat e.g. every second.